# Ответ NGINX о несуществующей странице

Tags: reactjs, nginx, http-status-code-404, nextjs

Есть ситуация, nginx возвращает 404 ответ в случае несуществующей странице если эту страницу ищут от корня домена site.ru/dfgd, и тут вроде все ок.

Есть сайт написанный на next.js
В каталоге есть страницы по адресу site.ru/catalog/razdel/[id_tovara].js
Получается что в [id_tovara.js] как я понял передается из адресной строки id товара, и генерируется страница с данными из db.

Но есть проблема, если вбить несуществующий id nginx вернет статус 200, хотя по идеи должен быть стату 404.
Подскажите, тут нужно с nginx разбираться или в сетингах самого сайта?
Если nginx, подскажите надстройку.

Answer (score 0):

nginx тут не при чем. Next должен вернуть, что такой страницы нет

[Вот здесь решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564921/how-to-set-status-code-404-instead-of-200-for-404-page-in-next-js?rq=1)

Comment: А nginx не может выполнить проверку на то что страница без контента и сделать редирект на 404?

Comment: например как у апач "ErrorDocument 404" ?

Comment: @Sirius_MkLain так она с контентом раз next что-то вернул. В общем нет, не может. Это задача next-а. Вернее, next должен вернуть 404 и тогда (правильно настроенный nginx) может показать какую-то свою 404 страничку.